# Selenium not opening Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox

So I am creating a simple bot to like people's posts, just for proof of concept and learning. I am using pycharm, along with selenium and geckodriver as my driver. As of now, I am simply trying to get the firefox web browser to open.

I have already added geckodriver to my PATH, and my computer recognizes Geckodriver. I have also tried using chromedriver and have it open chrome. The same thing happens, it simply does not open. Therefore, I feel as though there is a problem in my code or my external libraries, but I just can't seem to find it. Am I supposed to have some external library other than Python 3.7?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


class InstagramBot:

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    def closeBrowser(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        time.sleep(2)


        # "//a[@href'accounts/login']"
        # "//input [@name='username']"
        # "//input [@name='password']"

ig = InstagramBot("scumbag_scarbs, Sunny9999")
ig.login()
```

I expected it to open firefox and navigate to instagram.com. I do not recieve an error, but it just shows the program as running and not doing anything.

Please help, I found a bunch of people with problems similar to mine but nothing exactly the same.

Comment: > Am I supposed to have some external library other than Python 3.7?

yes.. you need selenium package for python.  which version do you have installed?

Comment: I have selenium 3.14 installed. I just installed it in my CMD though using pip, what else am I supposed to do? I can tell Pycharm recognizes selenium, as it comes up when i start typing it and it doesn't show any errors.

Comment: do you have a compatible version of geckodriver?